# Are 1-character string literals ever optimized to simple char type literals?

Tags: c++, char, newline, string-literals

Often when coding in C++, I will end `cout` statements with a newline (`\n`). However, my instinct has always been to express this newline as a string literal: `"\n"`, even though it is a single character and can be expressed more efficiently as a char literal (`'\n'`).
For instance:

```
cout << "The value of var is " << var << "\n";
```

There is a *lot* of code with this phenomenon. So, the question is as follows:

1. Is there **any difference whatsoever** in the efficiency of the two different ways of expressing the newline character constant? I am not concerned about making any actual difference in the execution of the produced program (which I guess would be trivial); rather it just bugs me that some efficiency, however minuscule, might be lost for no reason.
2. If the string-literal version is less efficient, will the compiler optimize it to the character constant version, as the two provide the exact same behavior?
3. I am also familiar with `std::endl`. The documentation says that "This manipulator is often mistakenly used when a simple newline is desired, leading to poor buffering performance." And points to [this article](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch25s02.html) for more information. However, that article states the the "poor performance" mentioned only applies to file I/O and that using `endl` for writing to the screen may actually improve performance. What's the deal with this?

I've searched the C++ standard library but couldn't find the implementations of the relevant overloads of the `<<` operator. I found the declarations in `ostream.tcc`:

```
extern template ostream& operator<<(ostream&, char);
extern template ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*);
```

But no clues as to how the mechanics boil down in the implementation.

This is more of a theoretical question than anything, so I'm not interested in reading "There is no *pratical* difference between the two." I know that. I'm just wondering whether there is any difference at all and how the compiler deals with that.

Comment: The only "one char string literal" that exists is an empty string.  Never forget about the zero terminator.

Comment: `"\n"` is of type `const char[2]`, how can that be *optimized* to a single character? Also, your question 3 seems unrelated, and probably should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: the OP is fully aware of the storage difference, guys. that is covered in the first paragraph. the OP asks whether the c string may be substituted by the compiler for this special one-character case. the single char needs no terminator.

Comment: @Praetorian: Certainly `'\n'` and `"\n"` are different, and the latter can't be optimized to the former *in general*. But `cout << '\n'` and `cout << "\n"` have exactly the same behavior, and a compiler is permitted to take advantage of its knowledge of `cout` and the overloaded `<<` operator to transform one to the other. Whether any compilers actually bother to do so is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are probably optimized to one string (per compilation unit) - most compilers will "merge strings of the same content".

I'd expect there to be very little practical difference, other than the fact that you pass a pointer to a single char string.

To your concrete questions:

1. Yes, there is a slight difference, as a `char *` will require some indirection and thus generate a few extra instructions to be executed. For console output (rather than output to file) it's not important, as scrolling the console, even in full-screen text mode is > 100x more instructions.
2. Doubt it.
3. So `std::endl` will flush the buffer, which does indeed reduce output to files, because partial sectors or blocks are being written to the file, which increases the system call overhead. If you use `"\n"`, the file is not being flushed until the buffer itself is filled, which would be at the very least 512 bytes, possibly as much as several tens of kilobytes. But as for answer #1, the console output performance will be more dependent on the speed that the screen can scroll.

Answer (score 2):

The different between string literal `\n` and `endl` is that:

`\n` is a string literal that get appended to stdout.
`endl` will also append the newline character to stdout, however, it will also flush the stdout buffer. Therefore, it may take more processing. Other than this, there should be no practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt it, because it changes both the memory layout (one has a null-terminator, the other does not), and because it would involve changing the actual type of the literal (and, by extension, changing the function that is called). It would therefore be an invalid transformation in the vast majority of cases, and not enough of a help in the tiny minority to count.

That said, if the compiler does enough aggressive inlining (inlining the function itself and the constant data into the function), you might end up with effectively the same code. For example, Clang compiles the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "X" << "\n";
    cout << "Y" << '\n';
}
```

into this:

```
movq    std::cout@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rsi
movq    %rbx, %rdi
movl    $1, %edx
callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rsi
movq    %rbx, %rdi
movl    $1, %edx
callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
leaq    L_.str2(%rip), %rsi
movq    %rbx, %rdi
movl    $1, %edx
callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
leaq    -9(%rbp), %rsi
movb    $10, -9(%rbp)
movq    %rbx, %rdi
movl    $1, %edx
callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
xorl    %eax, %eax
addq    $8, %rsp
popq    %rbx
popq    %rbp
```

As you can see, inlining has made the two cases nearly identical. (And, in fact, the `'\n'` case is slightly more complex because the character has to be put on the stack.)

Comment: On the other hand, I remember seeing `printf("\n")` being optimized to `putc('\n')`, so I wouldn't be so surprised by such an optimization.

Comment: `printf` is a C builtin that gets optimized in all sorts of ways. For example, `printf("blah\n")` turns into `puts("blah")`.